# unable to convert a QVariant back to a Python object

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

There is a problem with the 3rd argument in the emit signal line below. As shown, the program produces the error in the title:

```
exception_caught = pyqtSignal(str, str, types.TracebackType)

def exception_handler(self, excepthook):
    """Handler for uncaught exceptions

    :param excepthook: Exception handle function
    :type excepthook: function
    """
    def wrapper(error_type, error_obj, traceback):
        """Wrapper to handle the exceptions

        :param error_type: Exception class
        :type error_type: type

        :param error_obj: Exception instance
        :type error_obj: Exception

        :param traceback: Traceback object
        :type traceback: TracebackType
        """
        sys.callstats()
        self.exception_caught.emit(str(error_obj), "error", traceback)
        excepthook(error_type, error_obj, traceback)

    return wrapper
```

and if I try any other combination of:

```
PyQt_PyObject  
traceback: Optional[str]=None  
traceback: Optional[types.TracebackType]=None
```

Then, the error is that argument 3 is unexpectedly `None`.

Working with Qt5 5.7, PyQt5 5.7, Python3 3.5.1

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Your error and code must be reproducible and currently it is not.

Comment: Probably due to a problem with the rest of your program.